# Laravel - Many To Many Relationship Setup

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5 and am trying to get my head round relationships.

I have 2 tables, students and rooms.  Each room can have many students, and each student can have many rooms.

Would this be a Many to Many relationship in both directions?  Would I need a pivot table to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you describe is a many-to-many relationship, and for that you'll need a pivot table.

**Your three tables would look like this:** *(this might look different from your actual tables)*

`students`

```
id (primary key)
name
age
```

`rooms`

```
id (primary key)
room_size
bedroom_count
```

*Note: by default, the name of the pivot table is composed of both model names (in singular form), in alphabetical order. So in this case: Student + Room = room_student.*

`room_student` (pivot table)

```
room_id (foreign key to 'rooms')
student_id (foreign key to 'students')
```

**Pivot table migration:**

```
class CreateRoomStudentTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('room_student', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('room_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('student_id');

            // Primary key
            $table->primary(['room_id', 'student_id']);

            // Both foreign keys
            $table->foreign('room_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('rooms')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('student_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('students')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    // ...
```

**`Room` and `Student` models:**

```
class Room extends Model {
    // ...
    public function students()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(App\Student::class);
    }
}

class Student extends Model {
    // ...
    public function rooms()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(App\Room::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be a Many to Many relationship in both directions?

yes you need to Many to Many relationship in both directions

> Would I need a pivot table to achieve this?

yes

you can see more about Many to Many relationship [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement many to many relationship and you will definitely need pivot table for implementing many to many relationship.
In this case you can create pivot table like room_student and add the room_id and student_id columns in it. then just use define relationship using belongsToMany method in your models and remember to use the attach method whereever you want to attach the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need a pivot table.

About that, you can find out more from here:

[ManyToManyRelationship](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21)